# save plot (x- and y- coordinates, not graph or image) from wordVectors

Tags: r

I'm using the `wordVectors` package in R.  I ran the model and plotted the model in R.  Now, I would like to see the x- and y- coordinates that R used and also export the x- and y- coordinates to a CSV file so I can put it into another program like Tableau.

```
if (!require(wordVectors)) { 
  if (!(require(devtools))) { 
      install.packages("devtools")
  } 
  if (!(require(tidyverse))) { 
          install.packages("tidyverse")
 } 
 devtools::install_github("bmschmidt/wordVectors") 
}
library(wordVectors)
library(magrittr)
setwd("C:/Users/beckier/Desktop/Texts/test") 
prep_word2vec(origin="recipes",destination="recipes.txt",lowercase=T,
     bundle_ngrams=2) 
model=train_word2vec("recipes.txt","recipes_vectors.bin",
     vectors=200,threads=4,window=4,iter=5)
plot(model,perplexity=50)
```

[image]

Comment: you probably need to tell us to `devtools::install_github("bmschmidt/wordVectors")`, since this package isn't on CRAN AFAICT. Also, we would like a [mcve] please ... most likely, you will need to dig into the code of the plotting function to figure out what x and y it's using.

Comment: I'll post the code I used and show the output.... brb

Comment: if (!require(wordVectors)) {
if (!(require(devtools))) {
install.packages("devtools")}      if (!(require(tidyverse))) {         install.packages("tidyverse")}
     devtools::install_github("bmschmidt/wordVectors")
> library(wordVectors)
> library(magrittr)
> setwd("C:/Users/beckier/Desktop/Texts/test")
> prep_word2vec(origin="recipes",destination="recipes.txt",lowercase=T,bundle_ngrams=2)
> model=train_word2vec("recipes.txt","recipes_vectors.bin",vectors=200,threads=4,window=4,iter=5)
> plot(model,perplexity=50)

Comment: added image to orig post

Comment: how do I add the excel file I used to this post?